# tvOS change Cell Space

Tags: xcode, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

im trying to change the space between the Cells in a UICollectionView, i marked the border of the cell. http://prntscr.com/9cwgb1

```
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

i tried to set it with the layout but it only works if the scroll direction is vertical. Has someone got an idea ?